# Assert a pandas series contains only strings

Tags: python, pandas

My question seems so obvious I'm surprised it has not been answered before. Sorry if that is the case.

Currently the only assertion I can make is assert a series dtype is an object ('O'). But that does not certify it contains only strings as a mixed dtype series made of floats and ints for example is also of type 'O'.
Of course there would be the brute force method by asserting each element is of type string and using the apply function but that can be long and seems complex for a simple thing to check.

Is there any way to assert it really contains only strings, appart from a long apply on the series ?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with `all` + `isinstance` as well.

As an alternative, which can be more visual, you can `apply` the built-in `type` function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, '3', '4', '5']})

  col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

---

```
>>> df['col'].apply(type) == str

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Can do `(df['col'].apply(type) == str).all()` to check for all `True` values.

---

As a final note, using `type` can yield wrong results for subclasses of string.

e.g:

```
class mystr(str): 
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, '3', '4', mystr('5')]})
```

Notice the difference:

```
>>> df['col'].apply(type) == str
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

BUT

```
df['col'].apply(lambda s: isinstance(s, str))

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

So `isinstance` is the preferred checker in general.

Answer (score 2):

No easy way, but you can use `all` with a generator expression:

```
s = pd.Series(list('ABCD'))
>>> all(isinstance(x, str) for x in s)
True
```